# Rails assets pipeline debug in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, asset-pipeline

I have the following in config/environments/test.rb:

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.enabled = true
```

I get all my js files concatenated into application.js

However, when I do the same in development, I get javascript file included by itself.

Is there a way to make test (I'm using cucumber) behave like development?
The reason I'm asking is because I would like to be able to modify javascript and run my cucumber tests right away instead of having to do rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=test every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turns out I had a stupid hard coded line:

I had the following code and I suggest you never pass the :debug option to javascript_include_tag but instead, configure everything in your development.rb and test.rb.

```
<!-- watch out when passing the :debug option to javascript_include_tag -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", :debug => (Rails.env == "development") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your application.rb file you may need to add test to the following line:

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))

Comment: Doesn't seem to help... There's no similar line in my application.rb but development does work